# Protocol method self-referenced

Tags: objective-c, interface, protocols

In my iOS project, I create a protocol named "XMLElement" and I have a problem on a method of this protocol which must return an instance of my protocol :

```
@protocol XMLElement <NSObject>
-(XMLElement *) GetParent;
@end
```

The method **GetParent** returns the parent element which is XMLElement protocol implementation.

But this does not compile !

Must I have to return **id** object ? No other way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XMLElement is a protocol so you need

```
@protocol XMLElement <NSObject>
-(id <XMLElement>) GetParent;
@end
```

Not related to the problem: it is atypical to have a method name begin with an uppercase letter. It should be `getParent` rather than `GetParent`.

Answer (score 1):

A protocol is no type of its own, so you need to write:

```
- (id<XMLElement>) getParent;
```

(I recommend you stick to the conventions and start methods with lowercase letters)

Comment: Conventions also suggest you omit the `get`.